# How to move two pictures towards each other using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am tying to animate two face images using CSS3. They are horizontally aligned, and should move towards each other. [My current jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hfuGx/10/) is not working for some reason.

What's wrong with it?

```
<div id="screen">
    <div id="animation-01">
        <div class="face_turn_around">
            <img id="imgR" src="http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/face/face_right.png"
            />
            <img id="imgL" src="http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/face/face_left.png"
            />
        </div> <!-- END face_turn_around -->
    </div> <!-- END animation-01-->
</div> <!-- end TSCREEN -->

​ #screen {
    background: blue;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    height:300px;
    width:200px;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#imgL {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:30px;
}
#imgR {
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:30px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes face_turn_left {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 0px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes face_turn_right {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px);
    }
}
#animation-01 {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:face_turn_left;
    -webkit-animation-name:face_turn_right;
    -webkit-animation-duration:10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-unction:function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `position:absoulte` in `#imgL` and `#imgR` should be `position:absolute;`
2. `#animation-01` needs `position:relative;`. Otherwise, the faces would be positioned absolutely relative to `#screen`.

Updated fiddle (I changed delay to 1s so that you don't have to wait): http://jsfiddle.net/hfuGx/7/

When you want to have a separate animation for the two images, you need to attach the animation to the `<img>` elements, not on the parent. You can use two animations, or use one animation, where only `100%` (aka `to`) is set.

```
@-webkit-keyframes face_turn {
    to {left:50px;}
}
```

Currently, when your animation ends, the element goes back to its original state. If you want to maintain the last state, use the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property:

```
#imgL, #imgR {
    -webkit-animation-name: face_turn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* <-- This*/
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfuGx/14/

Comment: Yes thank you!
But how do you separate the heads so that the head comes  from the  right to the center.
Head left from the left side to the center.
They'll turn around and look at each other. Thank you

Comment: @yossi Then you have to attach the animation to the images, not on a container. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes Thx .Is it possible that the head look right and left? I use with

Comment: @yossi What do you mean? [`transforn:scale(-1,1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) will mirror the image, if that's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hfuGx/15/.

Comment: Yes Thx .Is it possible that the head look right and left? I use with `0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);left:50px;top:50px;}
40%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) scale(2);left:25%;top:450px;}
100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-50deg);left:200px;top:300px;}` to rotate the head but I can't sucsses

Comment: look on the head in this example you can rotate the head [Demo Link](http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/web-development/pure-css3-spiderman-ipad-cartoon-jquery-html5-no-flash.html)